# Spark Streaming Cleaning RDD checkpoint directories

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

We have spark streaming from kafka creating checkpoints in the HDFS server and its not getting cleaned up , Now we have millions of checkpoints in the HDFS. Is there a way to clean it automatically from spark ?

Spark Version 1.6
HDFS 2.70

[image: There are other random directories other than checkpoints which is not been cleared]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints", "true")
```

Cleaning should not be done automatically for all checkpoints, it is necessary to keep them around across spark invocations.As Spark Streaming saves intermediate state datasets as checkpoints and relies on them to recover from driver failures.

Comment: Thanks but I see random data other than checkpoints and it's not clearing it, do you have any idea whats that? added an image of that in the above question

Comment: Actually the last checkpoint of a spark job will not be cleaned, even if you set `--conf spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints=True`